# Data export from SQL Azure Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

We have a requirement to provide data in the form of a text file from our database to different vendors. The file should be generated on a daily basis. Is there any resource or application in azure that we can leverage in order to accomplish this?

Regards,
Lolek

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Functions to read from a SQL Azure database as explained on the following resource:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup

The following resource shows how you can write from an Azure Function to a BLOB storage account.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp.md#binding-at-runtime-via-imperative-bindings

The following article shows you how to schedule the Azure Function or automate its execution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Azure Data factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-azure-sql-connector) to export the desired data from Sql Azure, schedule the job to put the file in Blob storage.